# Creating a network from a text file of edges

Tags: java, file, networking, linked-list

This is my code at present:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

class Neighbor 
{
    public int vertexNum;
    public Neighbor next;
    public Neighbor(int vnum, Neighbor nbr) 
    {
            this.vertexNum = vnum;
            next = nbr;
    }
}


class Vertex 
{
    String name;
    Neighbor adjList;
    Vertex(String name, Neighbor neighbors) 
    {
            this.name = name;
            this.adjList = neighbors;
    }
}


public class Graph 
{

    Vertex[] adjLists;

    public Graph(String file) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(file));
        fileScanner.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z0-9]");

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (fileScanner.hasNext())
        {
            String nextWord = fileScanner.next();
            if (!words.contains(nextWord))
            {
                words.add(nextWord);
            }
        }

        adjLists = new Vertex[words.size()];

        // read vertices
        for (int v=0; v < adjLists.length; v++) 
        {
            adjLists[v] = new Vertex(fileScanner.next(), null);
        }

        // read edges
        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) 
        {
             // read vertex names and translate to vertex numbers
            int v1 = indexForName(fileScanner.next());
            int v2 = indexForName(fileScanner.next());

            // add v2 to front of v1's adjacency list and
            // add v1 to front of v2's adjacency list
            adjLists[v1].adjList = new Neighbor(v2, adjLists[v1].adjList);
            adjLists[v2].adjList = new Neighbor(v1, adjLists[v2].adjList);
        }
    }

    int indexForName(String name) 
    {
        for (int v=0; v < adjLists.length; v++) {
            if (adjLists[v].name.equals(name)) {
                return v;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }   

    public void print() 
    {
        System.out.println();
        for (int v=0; v < adjLists.length; v++) {
            System.out.print(adjLists[v].name);
            for (Neighbor nbr=adjLists[v].adjList; nbr != null;nbr=nbr.next) {
                System.out.print(" --> " + adjLists[nbr.vertexNum].name);
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws IOException 
    {
        Scanner br = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter graph input file name: ");
        String file = br.nextLine();
        Graph graph = new Graph(file);
        graph.print();
        br.close();

    }

}
```

So, I'm trying to use the ArrayList words to count all the unique words in my text file of edges. I'm then assigning the size of this arraylist as the size of my adjacency linked list so that it's the no. of nodes in the network.

This would be my text file, friendship.txt:

```
Sara Sam
Sara Ajay
Sam Sean
Sam Mira
Mira Jane
Jane Maria
Rahul Sapna
Sapna Rohit
```

I don't get any errors when the program compiles, but this is my runtime error: 
Enter graph input file name: friendship.txt

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at Graph.<init>(Graph.java:64)
    at Graph.main(Graph.java:109)
```

Comment: In the constructor you have a loop ```while (fileScanner.hasNext())```. After that loop finishes, there's no more data to read from the Scanner. Yet, a few lines later you do ```adjLists[v] = new Vertex(fileScanner.next(), null);``` and it throws an Exception.

Comment: @TheJavaGuy-IvanMilosavljević Oh jeez, I didn't even notice that, I'm modifying someone else's code and forgot to remove it. Thanks man